# Cannot restart SSH after adding host entry in sshd_config

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, sshd

What am I doing wrong?

I added within `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Host myserver
     HostName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
     User myuser
     Port 22
```

- When I try to restart `sshd`, I receive error:

  ```
  $ sudo systemctl restart sshd 

    Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
    See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
  ```
- Is there a syntax error in `sshd_config`?

  ```
  $ systemctl status ssh.service

    ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
      Loaded:   loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
      Active:   failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-07-31 14:08:15 EDT; 3min 31s ago
        Docs:   man:sshd(8)
                man:sshd_config(5)
      Process:  1780 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
          CPU:  3ms
  ```

  ```
  $ journalctl -xe

    My-VM sudo[1772]: myuser : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/www/example.com ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/b>
    My-VM sudo[1772]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by myuser(uid=1000)
    My-VM sudo[1772]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
  ```

Comment: That looks like a configuration for the ssh *client* (which goes in ~/.ssh/config or /etc/ssh/ssh_config), not the ssh**d** server (/etc/ssh/ssh**d**_config). The "d" at the end is extremely important.

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your host configuration is for a client, not a server, so put it in your client config file; usually: `$HOME/.ssh/config`

- This will tell you if there are any syntax errors in your server config file; usually: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

  ```
  sudo sshd -t
  ```